# Kafka 2.1.0 stream consumer stuck in rebalancing

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We are using KAfka Broker 2.10 and Kafka java driver 2.0.1 and Kafka Stream Driver 2.0.1.

We are using changelog to restore the state, it takes around 80-120 minutes. In meanwhile stream consumer for source topic stuck in rebalancing. After successfully restore the state, source topic consumer group is stuck in rebalancing

```
Properties config = new Properties();
config.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_SERVER_CONFIG, ENDPOINT);
config.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, busName);
config.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
config.put(StreamsConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "CLMB");
config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
config.put(StreamsConfig.NUM_STANDBY_REPLICAS_CONFIG, 1);
config.put(StreamsConfig.REPLICATION_FACTOR_CONFIG, 2);
config.put(StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG, 10);
config.put(StreamsConfig.STATE_DIR_CONFIG, STATE_DIR + "/streams");
config.put(ConsumerConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 40_000);
config.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 80_000);
config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
config.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 40000);
config.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_BYTES_CONFIG, 256 * 1024 * 1024);
config.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG, 32 * 1024 * 1024);
config.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, ENDPOINT);
config.put(ConsumerConfig.PARTITION_ASSIGNMENT_STRATEGY_CONFIG,Collections.singletonList(StickyAssignor.class));
config.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, "gzip");
config.put(ProducerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 120 * 1000);
config.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG,5000);
config.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG,2);
config.put(ProducerConfig.RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG,200L);
```

Comment: could you share the server logs?

Comment: Why do you say it get's stucked in rebalance? Pls share the evidence and possibly a bit more context. Number of messages, size range expected, any exceptions? also pls share the logs.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check any shrinking / expansion is going on your Kafka server.log.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are hitting this [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7181), in which case you can upgrade to 2.2 (or higher) and see if it is fixed.